# How to do search operation with @ngrx store?

Tags: angularjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have a contacts collection (contacts of all employees) in my angular app. It is similar to any contacts or address app where there are contacts and you can search for a name. When the search is done for a name like 'John', the app should show only names having 'John'.

The contacts are saved already in the `MSSQL DB`.

My question is about how should I manage the state with `@ngrx store`?

- Should I read all the contacts from the `MSSQL DB` when the app starts and then do the name search in the `@ngrx store` with a `reselect` selector to get the search results?
- Should I do the search in the `MSSQL DB` and then **clear and load** the `@ngrx store` with the search results every time when the search is done?

Answer (score 4):

2nd option, of course.

there is no point in downloading all the data.
you should have searchResults part of the store, update it on every search and do store.select(reducer.getSearchResults) to show it in your components.

if you would follow the same logic throughout the whole app with loading every piece of data you could ever need in your app lifetime you would end up with useless app very quickly ;)